# Is there a better (i.e. safer) way to eval math expressions without allowing the user to run real code?

Tags: python, input, eval, sanitization

I have a server running python which has the feature of acting as a simple calculator. I want it to be able to calculate things about as complex as a normal scientific calculator with simple functions. `1+1`, `4+(7*2)`, `sin(12)-3`, etc. A google search brought up `ast.literal_eval` but it seems to be useless for this case, as it only seems to handle one term at a time, and throws an error when given something simple like `1+1`. Here is the code I have now. Is there a better way to do this?

```
def safeeval(scaryuserinput):
    mathfunctions = 'acos|acosh|asin|asinh|atan|atan2|atanh|ceil|copysign|cos|cosh|degrees|e|erf|erfc|exp|expm1|fabs|factorial|floor|fmod|frexp|fsum|gamma|hypot|isinf|isnan|ldexp|lgamma|log|log10|log1p|modf|pi|pow|radians|sin|sinh|sqrt|tan|tanh|trunc'
    functions = []
    functionre = re.compile(mathfunctions)
    for x in re.findall(functionre, scaryuserinput):
        functions.append(x)
    scaryuserinput = scaryuserinput.replace("\x00", "")
    scaryuserinput = functionre.sub("\x00", scaryuserinput)
    scaryuserinput = ''.join([x for x in scaryuserinput if x in "1234567890+-/*^%(),.\x00"])
    for x in functions:
        scaryuserinput = scaryuserinput.replace("\x00", "math." + x, 1)
    return eval(scaryuserinput)
```

Comment: Libraries that use the AST parsing approach: https://github.com/danthedeckie/simpleeval and  http://newville.github.io/asteval/

Comment: @MartijnPieters simpleeval does the trick! Thanks!